# How to display JSON response into MVC view without predefining JSON structure?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm pretty new to ASP.NET and MVC. I've created a MVC asp.net app and I'm looking for a way to display the data i receive from **any** web API in my view without predefining the JSON structure of the response of my web API.

My controller which fetches the data from the web API looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> getCall()
{
    string url = "http://localhost:51080/";
    string customerApi = "customer/1";

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(customerApi);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string jsondata = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return Content(jsondata, "application/json");
        }
        return Json(1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

My View:

```
@using MVCApp.Controllers;

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
if (Session["userID"] == null)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Login/Index");
}
else
{
     ((HomeController)this.ViewContext.Controller).getCall();
}
}

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Getting started</h2>
    <p>
    <!-- Labels with values here! -->
    </p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
</div>
```

Hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you calling your controller `getCall()` method?

Comment: Have you considered doing the Json request directly from the frontend via ajax?

Comment: Robert: yes, but my api call is defined by which user is logged in, thats why i do this in the controller.

Comment: Why don't you want to predefine the structure? Is the API giving you different data each time? Or you want a generic view which can display output from any endpoint? It's not quite clear

Comment: @ADyson exactly, i want a generic view which can display output from any endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `JObject` from Json.Net to read the json opbject without defining a class.
An Example:

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": {
    "subkey1": 123
  },
  "key3": [
    3.1415926535,
    3.621,
    13.37
  ]
}
```

```
@{
string content = ...; // String containing the json data.
var json = JObject.Parse(content);
}
div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Getting started</h2>
    <p>key1: </p>
    <p>@json["key1"].Value<string>()</p><br>
    <!-- Returns "value1" -->
    <p>key2.subkey1: </p>
    <p>@json["key2"]["subkey1"].Value<int>()</p><br>
    <!-- Returns 123 -->
    <p>key3: </p>
    @foreach(var value in json["key3"].Values<double>())
    {
      <p>@value</p>
    }
    <!-- Returns -->
    <!-- 3.1415926535 -->
    <!-- 3.621 -->
    <!-- 13.37 -->
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good, but how do i pass the json reponse from my controller into my view and than use it with your example?

Comment: @NielsStenden if it was me I would make it part of your model, just like any other data you pass to a view

Comment: @ADyson, i dont know what api call is being executed, this is defined in another web configuration application so i can't predefine the data structure.

Comment: @NielsStenden that doesn't mean you can't make the `content` string a property of your model. That's what I was suggesting.

Comment: @ADyson So you suggest i make a model with getter and setter for "content"? I now pass the content object into my view, not sure how to deseralize it yet.

Comment: @NielsStenden "I now pass the content object into my view...how exactly though, if not part of the model? Using ViewData or something? Anyway `JObject.Parse(content);` in the code above is how you deserialise the JSON string.

Comment: Hey ADyson, I created another question so we can continue discussing about that problem there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55807751/how-to-parse-object-of-type-contentresult-content-in-asp-net-mvc-view