# How to parse object of type ContentResult.Content in asp.net MVC view?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, parsing

I'm calling a web API and the response is returned as an ContentResult.Content object. I retrieve this data in my asp.net MVC view and I'm trying to display this data in labels but I cant figure out how to parse this object into something i can work with.

Controller code:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> getCall()
    {
        string url = "http://localhost:51080/";
        string customerApi = "customer/1";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(customerApi);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string jsondata = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return Content(jsondata, "application/json");
            }
            return Json(1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

View:

```
@using MVCApp.Controllers;

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
if (Session["userID"] == null)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Login/Index");
}
}

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Getting started</h2>
    <p>
    <!-- Labels with values here! -->
    </p>
</div>
<p id="rData">
</p>
<div class="col-md-4">
</div>
</div>

@section scripts {
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('/Home/getCall/', function (data) {
      // parse object here
    });
});
</script>
}
```

Comment: If you issue is that you cannot/ are unable to send data to the controller, why don't you use an Ajax call and JSON.Stringify?

Comment: It's not the best way to do it. I think it's better to perform this check in controller action, not in the view. `((HomeController)this.ViewContext.Controller).getCall();` is definitely wrong.

Comment: @RomanKoliada Yes, i deleted this code. I'll adjust this.

Comment: @JamesS I dont want to send data to the controller, im recieving data from the controller in ContentResult.Content object, I'm not sure how to parse this into something i can work it.

Comment: @JamesS, this code does work but returns a string and I can't fetch elements of my json response because its a string now.

Comment: @NielsStenden, why don't you convert your string to Json then? => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22692540/convert-json-string-to-jsonresult-in-mvc